# adding numbers in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I tried to sum some numbers in a for loop but it didn't go as I expected

```
float sum = 0;
int i;

printf("0.1+0.1=%f\n", 0.1 + 0.1);

for (i = 0; i<1000000; i++)
{
    sum = sum + 0.1;

}
printf("the sum need to be 100000 \n");
printf("the real sum is:\n %f\n", sum);


system("PAUSE");
```

this program prints:

0.1+0.1=0.200000

the sum need to be 100000

the real sum is:

100958.343750

Press any key to continue . . .

can you explain please this strange result?

Comment: Fear not: almost every developer falls into this trap once. You really need to learn about how [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) work in computers. The important part is that floating point numbers cannot _exactly_ represent most numbers, you always have an error. In your case, the small errors add up until they become big.

Comment: thank you very much it has really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the international standard for floating point numbers does not have an exact representation for some decimal numbers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

It is due to the way they are stored in memory, the way the mantissa and exponent are stored.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

This is also the reason why you should never compare two float numbers even if they look "the same".

I still remember how surprised I was the fist time a simple code comparing two float numbers didn't work :) This alone would open a dedicated universe of discussions. It is very worth reading anyway:

http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Answer (score 0):

The floating numbers are stored in memory as `x*2^y` where x is between 0 and 1 with some precision and y is integer and so they accurately don't represent most numbers, they represent numbers "close enough".

When you do this addition multiple times, the error is just more visible.
You can use `double` type for better accuracy.